# Multiple VLANs with SAME ip (Ubuntu/Mint)

Tags: linux, ip, vlan

I'm in trouble seting up some of my linux machines.

I habe to use several vlan id's with the same ip address.

So I added several entries to my /etc/network/interfaces like this:

```
    auto eno1.42
    iface eno1.42 inet static 
    address 10.1.0.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 10.1.0.255
    vlan-raw-device eno1

    auto eno1.43
    iface eno1.43 inet static 
    address 10.1.0.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 10.1.0.255
    vlan-raw-device eno1
```

And so on. I did this on several debian based embedded systems (with eth0 instead of eno1) ... and it worked fine.

But when trying this with the newest releases of Ubuntu/Mint I came into trouble.

If I send a ping to another linux machine (based on debian), which is set up the same way - but with the ip 10.1.0.2  ...

```
    ping -I eno1.43 10.1.0.2
```

... I get no response.

But in wireshark I can see sometimes(!) a response also with the correct tag 43. But I can also see many many unanswered ARP requests from the debian based machine querying "Who has 10.1.0.1".

BTW: IP forwarding is enabled.

What am I doing wrong?

Have I to add an entry to the routing table?

Is there a better solution for this scenario (multiple VLANs on SAME ip)?

Answer (score 1):

Adding the same IP to multiple network interfaces won't work, no matter if it's a VLAN network interface, or something else. It won't work on embedded machines either, unless every single application binds to an interface (and you may have been lucky that applications which can't do that weren't active).

This very much looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), so please edit the question and describe *why* do you want to do this, and *what main goal* are you trying to achieve.

Having VLANs with overlapping IP ranges can also be the reason of major networking headaches, so don't do that.

If you really, *really* need to do funny things, you can create a network namespace for each VLAN. But it's probably much better to fix your setup.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
 
I for myself never would try this but its a predefined project requirement - please understand, I can not give details on the project.
 
Indeed I finally use only socket applications, using the interfaces, like eno1.42 and so on. I have 4 Rasperies running with exact this solution for 12 vlans - and it works smooth and fine, no issues in wireshark, also ping work (it would be no problem if just pinging does not work).
 
There is nothing special, just the entries, mentioned above.

Comment: `ping` can bind, so yes, `ping` will work. As will other applications. Applications without binding will fall flat on their face, though, and probably your Ubuntu/Mint has some of those. So either identify them and stop them, or put everything into network namespaces. Or give whoever came up with these project requirements a good talking to. I foresee lots of fun with debugging network issues in this project.

Comment: I think network namespaces are promising. I'll give them a try tonight ...